# How to import a local scala file in a Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: scala, import, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Jupyter Notebook to work with my Scala codes using the Toree notebook plugin.

How to import a locally saved Scala file (say `TweetData.scala`) in a notebook in the same directory?

Doing this directly, throws an error

```
In[1]:  import TweetData._

Out[1]: Name: Compile Error
        Message: <console>:17: error: not found: value TweetReader
            import TweetReader._
              ^
        StackTrace:
```

Comment: Other option will be creating a jar file and using it .

Comment: @ShankarKoirala Sounds like a good suggestion to get started for now. Could you please show how?

Comment: You can create a jar file from your current Scala class and add a library. Hope this helps https://medium.com/@DustinVanStee/how-to-add-a-custom-library-to-a-jupyter-scala-notebook-in-ibm-data-science-experience-dsx-d85e97bc2e10
If you are using only one file then you can copy paste and use it.

Comment: @ShankarKoirala Thanks, but is there a way to do this without SBT? Similar to how we can pack a JAR in Java? I feel that SBT needlessly complicates such a simple task.

Comment: Yeah, you can create a jar file without SBT. If you use any IDE intellij or eclipse it will create it

Comment: @ShankarKoirala I am able to build a JAR from the scala file, but the notebook couldn't find it; the import throws the same error. It was even simpler to compile the scala file using `scalac`. With the compiled `class` file in the current directory, the REPL had no trouble running the import. However the `ipynb` file opened in Jupyter Notebook (Toree Scala kernel) residing in the same directory still throws the same `not found` error.